# Want a:hover in one section to modify a <span> in another section

Tags: html, css

I have been working on this for a while and I am not finding a good answer to it.

**I have:**

```
<section class="s-one">
  <section class="s-two">
    <a class="a-one>
    </a>
      .
      .
      .
  </section>
</section>

<section class="s-three">
  <ul class="ul-one>
    <li>
      <span>xxx</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  .
  .
  .
</section>
```

When I hover over any one a element to modify it, I want to also modify a corresponding `span` element (an "a-one" pairs with the span in `ul` "ul-one, and so on).

I've tried all sorts of selectors and combinators, and so far all I can get is modifying all spans in s-three by using:

```
.s-one:hover ~ .s-two span { display: block;},
```

Not each individual one which would correspond to each individual `<a>`. Sorry if I am not clearer on this; I will be glad to provide clarification.

Comment: You can't do it with CSS in your above code. You could use the adjacent sibling selector if the `span` came right after the `<a>` or if the span was a child of the `<a>`. This could easily be done with JavaScript.

Comment: Notice you're missing a `"` in `<a class="a-one>` and `<ul class="ul-one>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick JS mock-up showing the behavior you want.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQGoej

```
<section class="s-one">
  <section class="s-two">
    <a class="a-one">I'm a link
      </a>
    </section>
  </section>

<section class="s-three">
  <ul class="ul-one">
    <li>
      <span>I'm a span</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

.hovered{
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').hover(function(){
    $('span').toggleClass("hovered");
  });
});
```